# How do I fix this blocking issue?

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, epoll

```
119             while(remainLength > 0){
120                if(remainLength >= MAX_LENGTH){
121                   log("WorkHandler::workLoop, remain %d > max %d \n", remainLength, MAX_LENGTH);
122                   currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, MAX_LENGTH, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
123                   log("currentSentLength %d \n", currentSentLength);
124                }
125                else{
126                   log("WorkHandler::workLoop, remain %d < max %d \n", remainLength, MAX_LENGTH);
127                   currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, remainLength, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
128                   log("currentSentLength %d \n", currentSentLength);
129                }
130
131
132                if(currentSentLength == -1){
133                   log("WorkHandler::workLoop, connection has been lost \n");
134                   break;
135                }
136                sBuffer += currentSentLength;
137                log("sBuffer %d\n", sBuffer);
138
139                remainLength -= currentSentLength;
140                log("remainLength %d \n", remainLength);
141
142             }
```

I have this code and the send function sometimes gets stuck. Some people points out that using non bloking I/O. I am using epoll so I think it is a little bit hard to change the whole design to non blocking mode. Is there any way to prevent blocking the send function?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `send` to block, you'll need non-blocking I/O. There's no way around that.

You don't have to put the socket in non-blocking mode though, the [`MSG_DONTWAIT`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) flag can be used on a per-call basis. But you *will* need to deal with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` error codes.

From the man page linked above:

> The flags argument is the bitwise OR of zero or more of the following flags.

so you can combine that with `MSG_NOSIGNAL`.

Comment: I am already using MSG_NOSIGNAL. Can I use both MSG_NOSIGNAL and MSG_DONTWAIT? Could you please show some sample code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the man page linked, it answers that question. You can find sample non-blocking code pretty easily with your favorite search engine (or this site's search feature for that matter).